# Is there an algorithm to determine if an arc through 3 points is concave up or concave down?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, algorithms

Armed with only the three points in 2-dimensional space,  $X = \{x_1, x_2, x_3\}$, is there a simple inequality or algorithm that can return whether or not an arc $A$ through these three points is concave upward or downward? If so, what is that algorithm?

Comment: If the curve joins points from left to right, $x_1$ being the leftmost and $x_3$ being the rightmost, then you could compute the line joining $x_1$ to $x_3$ and see if the middle point is above (implying concave down) or below (implying concave up) the line.

Comment: consider $X=\{(0,0),(\frac{\pi}{2},1),(1,000,000\pi,0)\}$ and the arc $\sin$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(x_1,y_1)$, $(x_2,y_2)$, and $(x_3,y_3)$ be the three points, with $x_1\lt x_2\lt x_3$.  Let $m_1=(y_2-y_1)/(x_2-x_1)$ and $m_2=(y_3-y_2)/(x_3-x_2)$.  If $m_1\lt m_2$, there is an arc that is concave up (but no arc that is concave down); if $m_1\gt m_2$, there is an arc that is concave down (but no arc that is concave up).